# Select after update in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update

Is there a way we can get the updated data from table in same query?

Something like following but in a single query call.

```
update table set columnA='newA' where columnB='oldB';
select * from table where  columnB='oldB';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [trigger](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjNyZHk9Kf5AhV7XvEDHePnCDsQFnoECAcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F8.0%2Fen%2Ftrigger-syntax.html&usg=AOvVaw1STmQcq9mmNWLy3aa0ot6V) for manage data after event fired but to execute two un related  query i think you can't do